# Assert.IsInstanceOfType cannot convert from object to System.Type

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm following apress mvc4 receipts book and I'm struggle with following example

```
// act
ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
// assert
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result.Model,typeof(List<Architect>))
```

this line

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result.Model,typeof(List<Architect>))
```

throws two errors

1. Argument1: cannot convert from object to System.Type
2. The best overloaded method match for Nunit.Framework.Assert.IsInstanceOfType(System.Type, object) has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to swap your arguments

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(List<Architect>),result.Model);
```

> The best overloaded method match for
>   Nunit.Framework.Assert.IsInstanceOfType(System.Type, object) has some
>   invalid arguments

It says that first argument is `System.Type`, **second** `object`